# iOS- How to make reloaddata of tableview in a CfReadStream

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new in iOS objective c and now I build an app that works with FtpServer to retrieve folder list and put in a UiTableView.

With this code I work with stream:

```
-(void) readStream {

CFURLRef ftpURL=(CFURLRef)url;

CFReadStreamRef readFTPStream=CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, ftpURL);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readFTPStream,kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName,userName);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readFTPStream,kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword,password);
CFReadStreamSetProperty (readFTPStream,kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode,NO);

MyStreamInfo streamInformation;
streamInformation.readStream=readFTPStream;


CFStreamClientContext clientContext={0,self,NULL,NULL,NULL};

CFOptionFlags events= kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred |    kCFStreamEventEndEncountered;



BOOL flagOpen=CFReadStreamSetClient(readFTPStream, events,(void*)didStartReceiveList, &clientContext);


if (flagOpen) {


    CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readFTPStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    //CFReadStreamUnscheduleFromRunLoop(readFTPStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopRunFinished);

}


if(!CFReadStreamOpen(readFTPStream)){
    NSLog(@"Could not open read stream");
}

NSLog(@"fine");
```

}

So I am the callbackFunction to receve event:

```
void didStartReceiveList(NSInputStream *stream,CFStreamEventTypeevent,CFStreamClientContext *clientContext) {


   //ViewController *self = (__bridge_transfer ViewController *)clientContext;


    ViewController *self=( ViewController *)clientContext;

switch(event) {
    case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:{

        [self readStreamData:(CFReadStreamRef)stream :clientContext];

    }
        break;
    case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred: {

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iFTP" 
                                                      message:[self message]
                                                     delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }

        break;
    case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:{
        //reload data

         **here in the reload i receive Signal crash**

        [self.tb reloadData];




    }
        break;
    }
```

}

**and this are the stream method**

```
-(void) readStreamData:(CFReadStreamRef) stream :(CFStreamClientContext*)  context {


MyStreamInfo *info=context->info;    
int offset=0;

CFIndex bytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(stream, info->buffer + offset,kMyBufferSize-offset);

if (bytesRead < 0) {

    CFErrorRef err=CFReadStreamCopyError(stream);
    CFStringRef str=CFErrorCopyDescription(err);
    NSString *descr=(__bridge_transfer NSString *)str;

    self.message=[NSString stringWithString:descr];
    fprintf(stderr, "CFReadStreamRead returned %ld: %s.", bytesRead,strerror(errno));
    CFRelease(err);

} else if (bytesRead == 0) {



    self.message=[[NSString alloc ]initWithString:@"Nothing to read"];
    fprintf(stderr, "CFReadStreamRead returned %ld: %s.", bytesRead,strerror(errno));
    //CFReadStreamClose(stream);


}

int bufSize = bytesRead + offset;
int totalBytesRead=0;
totalBytesRead+= bufSize;

int totalBytesConsumed=0;
CFIndex bytesReturned;

const UInt8 *newBuffer=info->buffer+totalBytesConsumed;
NSDictionary *d=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
if (bytesRead>0) {

    do {
        const UInt8 *buffRemaining=info->buffer+totalBytesConsumed;
        NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        CFDictionaryRef dictionaryParsed=(__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef)dict;
        bytesReturned=CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(NULL, newBuffer, bufSize, &dictionaryParsed);

        if (bytesReturned>0) {
            if (dictionaryParsed!=NULL) {

                d=(__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)dictionaryParsed;
                NSString *name=[d valueForKey:(NSString *)kCFFTPResourceName];
                [self.listEntries addObject:name];


            }


            totalBytesConsumed += bytesReturned;
            bufSize -= bytesReturned;
            info->leftOverByteCount = bufSize; 
    ;        newBuffer=info->buffer+totalBytesConsumed;

        } 
        else if (bytesReturned == 0) {

            info->leftOverByteCount = bufSize;
            totalBytesRead -= info->leftOverByteCount;
            memmove(info->buffer, buffRemaining, info->leftOverByteCount);
        } 

        else if (bytesReturned == -1) {
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iFTP" 
                                             message:@"CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing parse failure" 
                                            delegate:self 
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            break;
        }

    } while (bytesReturned>0 );

    //self.tb.delegate=self;
    //Add new records to the table
    //ViewController *self = (ViewController *)context;


    //[self.tb beginUpdates];
    NSMutableArray *iPath=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[listEntries count]; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *iP=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [iPath addObject:iP];
    }



}
```

}

The code work fine eccept when in the didreceiveStart callback at the event end I decide to reload data of my table view.
I don't know why I can't use in that point self.tableview reload data
Can someone help me?
Thank's

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tb dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

@try {
    cell.textLabel.text=[listEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",exception.reason);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);

}

cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

CGFloat r=255;
CGFloat g=140;
CGFloat b=0;


cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0];
return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

NSLog(@"%d",[listEntries count]);
return [listEntries count];
}
```

Comment: When you load the data do you provide this data to the table view data source before calling table view reload?

Comment: the data that you refer is NSMutableArray ListEntries? if this i init before to lauch callback and read stream,after in a stream event i fill the Listentries with the name of folders and at end i would reload the uitablew to see the result.

Comment: Is your table view created at that point in time?

Comment: my table is declare in .h like same @property(nonatomic,retain)UiTableView *tb; and Sybthesize in .m

Comment: Okay so your table is declared in your .h and synthesized in your .m (which gives it a setter and getter) but was it initialized and placed in the view hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry for my english you mean in the nib file?

Comment: It's all good. So you are using a nib file? Did you make sure to set the IBOutlet in the nib file to point to your UITableView? @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tb;

Comment: yes in .h IBOutlet UITableView * tb and in the IB i unit the delegate and datasource at file's owner and tb at the tableview.

Comment: In your provided code you showed this here in the reload i receive Signal crash what exactly was the error that happened there? Can you show the log?

Comment: When the compiler arrive at  [self.tb reloadData]; i receve this error Thread1:Program receive signal :EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Instead of [self.tb reloadData] try [tb reloadData]

Comment: it don't like: use on undeclared identifier 'tb' but is declared you know

Comment: Can you include your .h file and .m file in your post? From what you've said so far there shouldn't be an issue but for some reason your table view isn't even declared at that point in the code.

Comment: hi joe i have a problem to post .m and .h can you receve in other place?

Comment: Sorry I can't accept the files. You don't need to show your full .h and .m files if you can show the stuff pertaining to the tableview that would be good.

Comment: i had the pertaining of my tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your network event callbacks will be received asynchronously. So, on that thread - which is different to the main thread - you can't call `[self.tableview reloadData]` directly.

If you do, although the `reloadData` will probably be executed, it's unpredictable when.

The golden rule is that any UI operation - or in this cased UI related operation, i.e. a method that somewhere else has UI related code - must be done on the main thread.

The solution therefore is that you need to do this:

```
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```